# Terraform. Create a user in a secondary instance of Oracle Identity Cloud Service (IDCS)

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using Terraform to create several technical users for my applicationl, like this one:

```
resource "oci_identity_user" "scheduler_user" {
    compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
    name = "scheduler"
    description = "This user is used by the cron process."
}
```

It creates a user inside the primary user database of my OCI tenancy.

Oracle Cloud supports multiple user databases using one or more **secondary** instances of Identity Cloud Service. It is useful, if you want to separate users of a custom application.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/uaids/multiple-instances.html

The problem is that I have no idea, how to address this secondary IDCS instance from my Terraform script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity Cloud Service doesn't support Terraform, but has a fully-features REST API (or SDKs) that you can use:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/rest-api/index.html

You can either create users individual (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/rest-api/op-admin-v1-users-post.html) or through the bulk API if you want to do several at once (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/rest-api/op-admin-v1-bulk-post.html).

For example, to create users individually, make the following REST call:

```
curl
-X POST
-H "Content-Type:application/scim+json"
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access Token Value>"
https://tenant-base-url/admin/v1/Users
```

Passing in the following body:

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
  ],
  "userName": "bjensen@example.com",
  "name": {
    "familyName": "Jensen",
    "givenName": "Barbara",
    "middleName": "Jane"
  },
  "emails": [
    {
      "value": "bjensen@example.com",
      "type": "work",
      "primary": true
    }
  ]
}
```

You will need to obtain an access token from IDCS first so you can include that token in your authorization header. Refer to the Quick Start: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/rest-api/QuickStart.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30756321)

Comment: I've added an example